# Is it correct to say "They burst into laughs"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According to my research, the common expression is "**they burst into laughter**".

However, I came across [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-pRiAyxDps), and **at 4:44**, they say “**then they burst into laughs**”. The people in the video speak like native speakers.

Is it correct to say "**They burst into laughs**"?

Comment: It makes sense but it is not idiomatic. The grammar and punctuation in that video are frequently incorrect.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney, I posted a comment saying that "**English used in the video is not natural like a native**" and give some evidences,  and they disable my comment. They only show compliment comments. How bad!

Comment: The most common expression, I would say, is _they burst out laughing_.

Comment: @Tom - why would you expect anything different? They just want clicks. They don't want negative comments. They are not there to help you.

Comment: WOA looks like a very low quality site created by non-native people.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you are right, burst out laughing is about five times as common as burst into laughter. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=burst+out+laughing%2C+burst+into+laughter&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cburst%20out%20laughing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cburst%20into%20laughter%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, we are not native speakers, so we cannot figure out it's worthy to watch or not. We might learn wrong English.

Comment: @Tom - "We might learn wrong English" - indeed.

Comment: I tried the video. Very heavy American accents. I just caught the narrator saying 'mischievious', which is just wrong, or if you like, "non-standard" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mischievous)). I would avoid these videos.

Comment: "In the garden there was **an** sacred apple tree [which was] **planted** by the lake" Hmm

Comment: Look folks. The person READING the story is an American voice actor. The script is not written by a native English speaker -- even the title gives it away. "Story in English" Really? Then you have the switch from "God" to "the God".

Comment: @Tom If the title doesn't read like correct English, skip it.

Comment: Also, they have disabled ALL comments.

Comment: @Tom, if you are in the UK, why don't you and your kid watch [Cbeebies](https://www.bbc.co.uk/cbeebies)? it's from the BBC and they take a lot of care with the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idiomatic expressions would be:

- Burst into laughter
  or
- burst out laughing

"Burst into laughs" is not idiomatic. Don't be surprised when native speakers mix up their idioms. That video doesn't seem like a professional production, anyway - I skipped through it and heard at least two other mistakes.